# normalization of Chern-Simons lagrangian

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

I have noticed that there are two common choices for the coefficients in defining the Chern-Simons lagrangian:

$
S(A) = \frac{k}{8\pi^2}\int_M Tr(AdA + 2/3 A^3)
$
and 
$
S(A) = \frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M Tr(AdA + 2/3 A^3).
$
What is going on here, why the two different choices? In both cases, the parameter $k$ is always integer, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, a gauge transformation changes S(A) by an integer.  In the second case, by $2\pi$ times an integer.  The second case is a useful normalization for physicists, who care about the behavior of  $exp(iS(A))$.  The first case is probably a more sensible convention for doing differential geometry, but I don't actually know where it's used.